# Test-connection for remote pcs

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell with the aim of collecting a reg value from a list of remote machines, Ive tried using a test-connection to speed up process where devices are not online but the test-connection fails for all....

Here is the script:

```
clear
$servers = Get-Content -Path C:\ukdeviceswin10.txt


$PatternSID = 'S-1-5-21-\d+-\d+\-\d+\-\d+$'

$ProfileList = ForEach ($server in $servers) 
{ if(test-connection $server -quiet -count 1)
{

invoke-command -computername $server {gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*' | Where-Object {$_.PSChildName -match $PatternSID} | 
    Select  @{name="SID";expression={$_.PSChildName}}}}


foreach ($profile in $profilelist) {
$profile = $profile -replace ".$"
$profile = $profile.substring(6,46)
$profile = $profile -replace "[;]"
$profile = $profile -replace "[ ]"
$profiletest = $profile.substring(0,8)

if ($profiletest -eq "S-1-5-21"){
$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::Users, "$server") 

$profilekey = $profile + "\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Office\\Outlook\\Addins\\CofenseOutlookReporter.AddinModule"

$RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("$profilekey")
if ($regKey -eq $null){} else {$LoadbehaviourVersion = $RegKey.GetValue("LoadBehaviour")
$results = $server + " " + $profile + " " + $LoadbehaviourVersion | out-file -filepath c:\dell\regresults.txt -Append
} 


$RegKey=""
$LoadbehaviourVersion=""

}
}
}
```

Comment: What's the error message of `test-connection`?

Comment: Did you try *by hand* to `test-connection`, **without** the `-quiet` switch ?

Comment: andpleaseindentyourcodeifyouexpectpeopletoreadit

Comment: test-connection works fine as a single liner but doesn't when I add it in the script

Comment: In that case, I suggest you show what is in your file `ukdeviceswin10.txt`

Comment: P.S. You should Close the opened `$Reg` and `$RegKey` at the end of the loop. `$RegKey.Close(); $Reg.Close()` and you shouldn't really double up all backslashes in the key path.